# Need to make a simple login page using hard coded username and password with php

Tags: php, session, authentication

So in this smaller project I have made a very simple page containing guest book entries.

My index.php contains code that is linked to a local MySQL database and then the entries you make is shown on the page.

This is the 2 pages I have:

Index.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);              // Report all type of errors
ini_set("display_errors", 1);     // Display all errors
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Guestbook</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stilmall.css?<?php echo time(); ?>" type="text/css">
<body>

<nav id="mainmenu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="login.php">Administration</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

<div class="posts">

<h3>Add post:</h3>


<?php 
    include("includes/config.php");


    $user = new Users();

    /*// Radera
    if(isset($_GET['deleteid'])) {
        $id = $_GET['deleteid'];

        if($user->deleteUser($id)) {
            echo "<p> Post Deleted</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p> Error trying to delete post</p>";
        }
    }
        */
    // new post
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $post = $_POST["post"];

        if( $user->addUser($name, $post)) {
        echo("<p> Post added to board! </p>");
    } else {
        echo("<p> Error trying to add post to board </p>");
    }
    }




?>

<form method="post" action="index.php">
        Username: <input type="text" name="name">
        Content: <input type="text" name="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Post" name="submit">

</form>


<h3>Existing Posts</h3>

<?php
    //show posts

    $userlist = $user->getUsers();

    foreach($userlist as $c) {

        echo  $c["name"] . " - " . $c["post"] . "<br>" . "Posted: " . $c["postdate"] . "<br><br>";
    }
?>



</p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And then the second page:

```
<?php



        class Users {

            private $db;
            private $name;
            private $post;



            //contructor

            function __construct() {
                // connect to db


                $this->db = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBDATABASE);
                if($this->db->connect_errno > 0) {
                    die("Fel vid anslutning " . $this->db->connect_error);
                }

            }


            // get users

            function getUsers() {
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY postdate DESC";
                    $result = $this->db->query($sql);

                    return mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            }

            // add user
            function addUser($name, $post) {
                //control if correct values have been entered
                if(!$this->setUser($name)) { return false; }
                if(!$this->setPost($post)) { return false; }
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(name,post)values('" . $this->name . "', '" . $this->post ."');";

                    return $result = $this->db->query($sql);

            }

            //delete user

            function deleteUser($id) {
                $id = intval($id);
                $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id=$id";
                return $this->db->query($sql);

            }

            // set och get methods

            function setUser($name) {

                if($name != "") {
                    $this->name = $this->db->real_escape_string($name);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }

            }



            function setPost($post) {

                if($post != "") {
                    $this->post = $this->db->real_escape_string($post);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }

            }
        }






  ?>
```

All this is working but I need to make a small form where you enter a hardcoded username and password like "User" and "Password" in the form, and then it takes me to a almost identical page with a login session i will make called admin.php, where its the same page just a "delete" option anchored to each post.

Ive been trying for a while but cant seem to figure this out.

If there anyone out there that knows how can in the most simple way Make a login function(hard coded login values) that creates a session and takes me to my new page, where there also is a simple "logout" button that take me back to the index page I would be grateful.

Comment: "where you enter a hardcoded username" - is either an oxymoron or self-modifying code. Both of which are bad.

Comment: Its not suppose to be safe, its just the assignment for this task to have it to a preset login information. To just check if the form contains the information "username" and "password" and if it does log you in to another page

Comment: If you asked me how you should trepan yourself with a spoon I would tell you its a bad idea and not to do it. This is no different.

Comment: In my sstudies I have been requested to make a login where this time the login info you should enter is preset in the code, this is how the assignment is and how Im supposed to solve it. Thats it. So thats why Im asking for help about just this issue im having. I fully understand its not safe or how you normally do it but thats the case now mate so If you can please not clutter up the comment section and leave space for someone that is actually willing to help me that would be nice, thankyou

Comment: Ah... homework assignment. I'm out.

Comment: If you are posting the username and password to your script you can create an additional if statement for checking if the username and password are equal to the 2 hardcoded values if this is true you can do something entirely different.

Comment: Any idea how i can create and send a session to the new page?